# Countdown timer is restarting evertime I hit refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Whenever I refresh my browser its restarting from the start. I uploaded  it on server..I'm getting the same result.
Here's my code:

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 33 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
#clockdiv {
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: #001a00;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle- [code](https://jsfiddle.net/wbqzrmk8/)

What am I doing wrong here?
At first I thought it'll be fine if I upload it on server..but still getting the same result.
If there's another code..please help me out or guide me..how to do it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 33 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

every time you load the script, it will always be 33 days (and so on) from now. So you'll have to give the script a fixed deadline like so:

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse('2017-10-12'));
```

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Sorry, yes. I was typing while you posted it. But thank you for taking the time to point that out. By the way you are creating an object in your line of code you don't need. I meant to help. Sorry again.

Comment: Aah beautiful! Thanks..it looks clean :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because of this line

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 33 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

You keep setting the date to 33 days in the future, so every time the page loads this is set.

If you change this line to the following and pass in your desired date.

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse('2017-10-30'));
```

Run code snippet below.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse('2017-10-30'));
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
#clockdiv {
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: #001a00;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh man! Thank you so much. I've been going crazy over this. Thank you..cheers! :)

Comment: Yes, this answer is right and was first. Just a quick comment: `new Date(Date.parse(new Date('2017-10-30T00:00:00')));` could be `new Date(Date.parse('2017-10-30T00:00:00'));`